# Highcharts dataLabel positioning issue in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I'm trying find how to position the labels inside the bars in this case.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    subtitle: { text: 'Some syubtext' },
    xAxis: [{ categories: ['2009','2010','2011','2012','2013'] }],
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: { stacking: 'percent', 
              dataLabels: { 
                  enabled: true, 
                  color: 'white'
              }
             }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [28, 23.6, 19.4, 17.5, 22]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [56.7, 60.4, 64, 64.8, 60]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [15.3, 15.9, 16.6, 17.7, 18]
    }]
});
```

});

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbf74c1d/1/)

This works on Chrome, but FF and IE displaces the data labels.
Please advice.

Comment: I think it's the same as bug reported on the Highcharts [github](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3872).

Answer (score 1):

adding verticalAlign: 'top' fixes the issue

```
dataLabels: { 
    enabled: true, 
    color: 'white',
    verticalAlign: 'top'
}
```

fiddle amended http://jsfiddle.net/cbf74c1d/2/

Comment: Sorry man, but it doesnt work. I tried all the options of vertical align before i post this question

Comment: http://gyazo.com/f530ca0e9d6817f832adf1255676ad9d works on firefox 32.0.3, without vertical align the longer labels appear too high

Comment: http://bksito.com/screen.gif , sorry man. I don't know what browser you are using, but your jsfiddle doesn't work

Comment: That was OSX firefox 32.0.3, this is windows firefox 35.0.1 - http://gyazo.com/17087615849a068a3325ce3909f29e8f and this is IE 11 win 8.1 http://gyazo.com/4ba324738a9554a13b211ac6da22cb26

Comment: and this is 35.0.1 osx firefox http://gyazo.com/d4b178398766984706c6e972f9c76f39, works in all of the above

Comment: I'm not the only one with this issue man. If i knew what is the problem i would fix it. As you see on my screen this fiddle doesn't work as expected. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: I run this example in FF35.0.1 / windows7 and also all works properly. Which OS you have?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate. But it happens to other OSes too.

Comment: Windows 7 running Firefox 36.0 - http://gyazo.com/0b851dcc9b25082b5bfd78cad1d314e5 I'm out.